# Install programm on computer

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar, installation

I have jar file.

Also I have batch file, which contains:

> start javaw -jar Name.jar

I want make .exe-file, which copy jar-file in choosen folder and add batch-file to autorun.

How I may make it?

Answer (score 1):

You need corresponding tool called like "installer creator".

Some of the most popular are InstallForge - http://installforge.net/ and NSIS - http://nsis.sourceforge.net/.

Second one looks more complex, but can provide anything you only need.